# C# String.Format and object as argument

Tags: object, c#-4.0, format, arguments

Here is my idea
I am reading a string from my .resx file

And here is a sample of such string :*"I am writing this from {}"*

I wrote a function to pass values to those arguments. I don't know the number of arguments expected by the string

```
    public string MyFormattedString (string resourceName, object param=null)
    {
        string fStr= Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(resourceName);

        fStr= string.Format(fStr, param);

        return fStr;
    }
```

If I call my function with MyFormattedString ("resourceName", "noWhere"), I do not get what I am expecting
What's wrong?

Comment: What output are you expecting? What output do you actually get? Why are you calling the function with the string "noWhere"? It doesn't have any format items, so there's nothing for `String.Format` to replace.

Comment: I am getting "I am writing this from" and the argument value is not inserted

Comment: Post your full code, including where you *call* that method. No one can help you with your problem until they know what you're actually doing.

Comment: Would String.Format(fstr, param) work if param=null? Wouldn't it crash with ArgumentNullException? Most likely case you have no indexed placeholders in the format (like "this is format {} in your question").

Comment: @Vijay: We've already run at all that. Apparently the code shown in the question contains a typo, and everything is already correct. Guessing won't help, the asker refuses to show his code, despite repeated asking. Not worth trying to help anymore.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution to my issue with using **params object[]** I just discovered

```
public string MyFormattedString (string resourceName,  params object[] param)
{
    string fStr= Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(resourceName);

    fStr= string.Format(fStr, param);

    return fStr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The resource string should be `"I am writing this from {0}"` with a numeric position in it.

Comment: It was a typo in question
It is effectively "I am writing this from {0}"